# Using \jobname in Overleaf to get the tex file name

Tags: overleaf, jobname

I use Overleaf and the `\jobname` macro becomes useless because it always expands to "output". Is there any workaround?

Comment: you surely know the name of the file you uploaded so you can use that directly, why do you need a command?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I create a new tex file for every homework problem set, like Homework1.tex. Then I have to type that again for `\maketitle`. I want to know if it's possible to automate this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure this is really needed but you can get `latexmk` to record the original filename, for example

**latexmkrc**

```
$pdflatex="echo %A > jobname.tex ; pdflatex %O %S"
```

leaves the original file name in `jobname.tex` which you can `\input` in your main file:

**wibble.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{\input{jobname}}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I do not see the intermediate file jobname.tex represented on the leftmost column on the screen, but thankfully it does work.

Comment: @LongHorn On overleaf intermediate files are not shown in the left pane. To download it you click somewhere in the log button (?)

Answer (score 9):

Using the `realmainfile` option with the `currfile` package might be useful, too. `\currfilebase` should then expand to your actual file name.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[realmainfile]{currfile}
\title{\currfilebase}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry as I'm unable to accept two answers at the same time, but your solution works equally well and is more concise!